Run Ultralytics with limited TQDM output
I use nohup statement to redirect to train.log file and disown to disconnect the process from the terminal. However, the built-in TQDM of Ultralytics will occupy a large amount of output, resulting in a very large log file, which is very troublesome to read in VS Code.
nohup \
/home/Lee/miniconda3/envs/rtdetr/bin/python /home/Lee/Code/rtdetr/train0.py  \
> train0.log 2>&1 &
disown

I tried modifying ultralytics/engine/trainer.
pbar = TQDM(enumerate(self.train_loader), total=nb,mininterval=10.0)

mininterval=10.0 doesn't seem to work because of the custom TQDM used by Ultralytics

What is your question? Why the "linux" tag? Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask].
